# Really slow execution

Tags: mysql, performance, database, percona

I own a wordpress installation, and Updated to 3.4.1.

After the upgrade, I got a very strange slowdown to my wordpress.

After all, I used the

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

in my wp-config.php with combined with the following code in my theme footer.php

```
global $wpdb;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($wpdb->queries);
echo "</pre>";
```

and I found that while I don't have many queries (49 queries I got), there are

- 4 Quiries took more than 9''
- 3 Quiries took more than 8''
- 4 Quiries took more than 7''
- 4 Quiries took more than 6''
- 8 Quiries took more than 5''
- 1 Quiry took more than 4''

Here I will show you some of the queries:

```
/* Execution time 7.0095062E-5 */
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY t.name ASC

/* Execution time 5.3167343E-5 */
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (77375,77379,77381)

/* Execution time 9.2029572E-5 */
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (77381,77379,77375)
```

In most of the queries there query is simple, with no complexity, and I cannot imagine why that queries are so slow.

The WordPress database contains in about 60.000 records and running on percona.

Any idea for that issue and how maybe can I fix it ?

Comment: How long does the query take if you run it by hand against mysql (try different IDs to avoid cached data)?  Are you on any kind of shared/virtual host where something unrelated could be screwing with your IO speed?

Comment: The server is dedicated with 12GB Ram installed.